# Add 0's to the end of an integer

Tags: java

```
for(i=0; i<array.length; i++){
  sum = 4 * 5;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is add ((array.length - 1) - i) 0's to the value of sum. For this example assume array length is 3. sum equals 20. So for the first iteration of the loop i want to add ((3 - 1) - 0) 0's to the value of sum, so sum would be 2000. The next iteration would be ((3 - 1) - 1) 0's. so sum would equal 200 and so on. I hope what I am trying to achieve is clear.

So my questions are:

Is it possible to just shift an int to add extra digits? My search thus far suggests it is not.

If not, how can i achieve my desired goal?

Thankyou for reading my question and any help would be greatly apreciated.

Comment: Multiply by 10 n times?

Comment: you don't need to run through the whole array to calculate number of zeros to be appended... you can do that in O(1)

Comment: For what he is asking he needs to loop size of array.

Comment: Okie.. I thought he just wants the final answer

Answer (score 4):

You can just multiply it by 10 however many times.

```
200 * 10 = 2000
```

etc

So in your case, you'd have to use a for loop until the end of the array and multiply `sum` every iteration. Be careful though, because the max value of an `int` is 2^31, so it of surpasses that, it will roll back to 0

Answer (score 1):

You can add `n` zeroes to the end of a number, `sum` by multiplying `sum` by `10 * n`.

```
int sum = 20;
for (int i = 0; i < ary.length; ++i) {
    int zeroesToAdd = ary.length - 1 - i
    sum *= (zeroesToAdd > 0) ? zeroesToAdd * 10 : 1
}
System.out.println("Sum after loop: " + sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=array.length; i>0; i--){
  sum = 20;
  for(int j=0; j < (i - 1); j++)
  {
     sum *= 10;
  }
}
```

Use inner loop to multiply by 10 the number of times i is for that iteration. You would need to reset sum in your outer loop each time.

Comment: Thankyou for your reply. I was hoping to avoid using a second loop but maybe I will have to.

Comment: No problem man I think this is your best bet. I don't know of another way of doing it.  Maybe someone else will though.  You could use recursion but that may be worse.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply by `10` instead, and use `<` (not `>`) like

```
int sum = 20;
int[] array = { 1, 2, 3 };
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    int powSum = sum;
    for (int j = array.length - 1; j > i; j--) {
        powSum *= 10;               
    }
    System.out.println(powSum);
}
```

Output is (as requested)

```
2000
200
20
```

Comment: This works great for the question I asked. I misunderstood what I was suppose to be doing though so this didn't work for me but I have adapted this to work for my situation. Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

1. You will want to check your for-loop condition: `i>array.length`. Since `i` starts at 0, this loop will not run unless the array's length is also 0 (an empty array). The correct condition is `i < array.length`.
2. This "shift" you want can be achieved by creating a temporary variable inside the loop that is equal to the sum times 10<sup>i</sup>. In Java's Math library, there is a `pow(a,b)` function that computes a<sup>b</sup>. With that in mind, what you want is something like this:

---

```
int oldSum = 4 * 5;

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    int newSum = oldSum * Math.pow(10,i);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, the loop in my code is i<array.length. I just typed it wrong on here. Should have pasted it really. Your solution is interesting though. The loop i put in the question isnt exactly what i have in my code, it was just an example so this wont work as it is but i see what you are saying so i will try to implement this. Thankyou for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

<s>For array of length = **n**; you will end up adding `(n - 1) + (n - 2) + ... + 2 + 1 + 0` zeros for `i = 0, 1, ... n-2, n-1` respectively.</s>

Therefore, number of zeros to append **(z)** = `n * (n-1) / 2`

So the answer is `sum * (10 ^ z)`

**[EDIT]**
The above can be used to find the answer after N iteration. (I miss read the question)

```
int n = array.length;
long sum = 20;
long pow = Math.pow(10, n-1); // for i = 0
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    System.out.println(sum*pow);
    pow /= 10;
}
```

Comment: Aha, I was trying to make sense of what you had said. Thanks for editing. I quite like this approach, It's similar to Victors. Thanks for the help